# Composer Init command gives TypeError on Author/Name (Composer 2.3.7)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, composer-php

Hi guys i ve a little misunderstanding with Composer. I get error wrote 'Composer Init' in vsc Terminal, though composer is installed.

I checked composer -V in cmd and it tells that i have  'version 2.3.7' installed.

But in Visual Studio Code terminal I
write 'composer init' to generate composer.json file and get this kind of error:

```
 In InitCommand.php line 465:
                                                                                                                                                                           
    [TypeError]                                                                                                                                                                  
    Composer\Command\InitCommand::parseAuthorString(): Argument #1 ($author) must be of type 
    string, 
    null given, called in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.ph   
    ar/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php on line 345
```

Comment: Is this your first time running `composer init` in this project? Is there a composer.json file already present?

Comment: Please run `composer diagnose`  and post the output to add a bit more context to your question. The error message so far just shows a programming error in composer itself, perhaps a pre-condition in your systems environment is not fulfilled (this may not be your fault, just for your information). Using the `-vvv` switch can give you more information, like a backtrace that you can then compare against the source-code of composer in that version (available on Github).

Comment: When `composer init` asks you for an author name, enter `n`  or `no`, alternatively enter an author name (not an empty string). One of the two options should enable you to use the `composer init` command despite this error.

Comment: Thanks man it solved the Problem. I enterd my Name and thats all.   Yes its first Time I use it. I  decited to level up On MVC Model. thanks guys it was very helpfull!

Comment: @DavitShavliashvili: Also added an answer so that this question can be marked as solved. Please accept the answer. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused in Composer 2.3.7 when being asked for the authors name in `composer init` and then entering nothing while not having the git author or the composer default author in the environment.

Either enter `n` or `no` to leave the username empty or enter a non-empty author name.

This is patched in Composer version 2.3.8 (Release date: 1st of July 2022).

The type error is a regression. Composer 2.2.x / 1.10.x are not affected.